# Sum of Little o(1/n) Terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I have a question about the little-oh notation:
If every $h_i=o(1/n)$, then consider $ \sum_i^n h_i$. Is the sum $o(1)$?

Currently, I am trying to derive it by definition, but I am quite unsure about exchanging limit and sum:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{|\sum_i^n h_i|}{1/n}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_i^n |h_i|}{1/n}=\sum_i^n \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{| h_i|}{1/n}=\sum_i^n0=0$

Is the above derivation right? How can I correct it?

Thank you!

=======================
Thank you very much for the counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about how $h_i$ depends on $i$, we can't say anything. For example, if $h_i = \frac{i^2}{n^2}$, we'd say that $h_i = o(\frac1n)$, however,
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^n h_i = \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n} = \Theta(n). 
$$

Comment: thanks! if we consider  $n\times o(1/n)$, will that be o(1)?

Comment: Yes, so we can say for example that $n \cdot h_i = o(1)$ for any single $i$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't interchange the limit and sum, because the summation goes up to $n$ and that is not defined if the summation is outside the limit.

Consider now $h_i=i^2/n^2$. Then $h_i=o(1/n)$, but $\sum_{i=n}^n h_i\to \infty$.

Comment: hanks! if we consider n×o(1/n), will that be o(1)?